# How to process a large XML file using Hadoop?

Tags: xml, hadoop

I have a 3 GB XML file with 600K records that I need to process with Hadoop on daily bases. Basically I need those records to be stored in Hbase.
What is an efficient way of doing this? Should I split the file and have multiple mappers processing the files? Can you recommend a fast way of doing the splitting?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the xml file? Because I thinking it matters how deep the nesting is, maybe the the format of the data will facilitate things (the custom key, the size of a record reader etc).

Comment: You might have a look at Mahout's `XMLInputFormat` and this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12683304/1050422

Answer (score 0):

If you split the file, there are command-line xml file splitters you can call from your code. Some are commercial, some OS. Google "split large xml"