# Should I add a custom getSplits implementation for Hadoop XMLInputFormat?

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, mapreduce

**Background:**

See this question: [Parsing XmlInputFormat element larger than hdfs block size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639745/parsing-xmlinputformat-element-larger-than-hdfs-block-size/) and its answer.

Suppose I want to parse Wikipedia's pages-articles bz2 compressed XML dumps using Hadoop using Mahout's `XMLInputFormat`. My input can be of two types:

1. XXwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream-index.txt.bz2
2. XXwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2

The first one is a splittable compressed type, and by default (given `BZip2Codec` is enabled) it will be splitted and multiple mappers will be used to process each decompressed BZ2 split in parallel.

The second type is directly bz2 compressed, and therefore not splittable I guess? The default `getSplits` implementation that `XMLInputFormat` uses is `FileInputFormat.getSplits` which I presume makes unintelligent vanilla splits having no knowledge of my XML schema. I think this might impact performance.

**Question:**

1. Does `XMLInputFormat` work with unsplittable bz2 compressed files, that is, raw text directly bzipped, and not multistream bz2 (concatenated)? By work I mean in parallel, with multiple mappers and not feed everything into a single mapper.
2. Will it be beneficial to me if I implement a custom `getSplits` method like https://github.com/whym/wikihadoop#splitting? Also see https://github.com/whym/wikihadoop/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wikimedia/wikihadoop/StreamWikiDumpInputFormat.java#L146 - this InputFormat uses a custom `getSplits` implementation. Why?

Comment: Have you found any clue on this?